# Given a function f which is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is smooth and $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$.

Proof that $\exists  x_1,x_2 \in [0;1] \mspace{7mu} (x_1\neq x_2 )$ such that

$\frac{1}{f'(x_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(x_2)}=2$ .

By the Lagrange Mean value theorem $\exists x_0 \in [0;1]$ such tat $f'(x_0)=1$. If $x_1=x_2=x_0$, it's OK, but $x_1 \neq x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g_1 = \min_{x \in [0,1]} f'(x)$, $g_2 = \max_{x \in [0,1]} f'(x)$. Note that $\int_0^1 f'(x)dx = f(1)-f(0) = 1$
and so $g_1 \le 1 \le g_2$.

If $g_1 < 1$ then we must have $g_2 >1$ and vice versa, otherwise we would have
$\int_0^1 f'(x)dx <1$ (or $>1$ as the case may be). Otherwise we have $g_1=1=g_2$.

In the latter case we can pick $x_1 = { 1 \over 4}, x_2 = {3 \over 4}$ to get the desired result.

In the former case, since $g_1 < 1$ we see that there is some $\delta>0$ such that $[1,1+\delta)$ is contained in the set of values $R=\{ {1 \over f(x) } \}_{x \in [0,1], f(x) \neq 0} $ and similarly since $g_2>1$ there is some $\delta'>0$ such that $(1-\delta',1] \subset R$. Let $\phi(t) = {1 \over 2-{1 \over t}}$, and note that $\phi(1) = 1$ and $\phi'(1) =-1$. In particular,
we can find some $t \in (1,1+\delta)$ such that $\phi(t)\in (1-\delta',1)$.

We can find distinct $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1) = t, f(x_2) = \phi(t)$ from which the result follows.